# Negatively buffer edges of thermal resolution raster layer to fit within a higher resolution RGB raster layer to avoid soil temperature extraction

Tags: raster, value-extraction

I want to exclude overhanging thermal pixels in a raster layer to fit within a higher resolution RGB raster layer to avoid extracting any soil temperature.

I have tried buffering in QGIS but will only edit vector layers.

I have tried CN spectral sharpening, Gram-Schmidt Pan Sharpening and HSV Sharpening in ENVI 5.5.3.

Please see example below

First image is RGB canopy cover.
Second Image is thermal canopy cover.
[image: Canopy Cover RGB]

[image: Canopy Cover Thermal]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please [Edit] your Question to specify what GIS software you are using and what you have tried